# How in smarty format 10000 to 10 000

Tags: smarty

first, i am sorry for bad English.

I need modify integer number from 10000 to 10 000, or 999888777 to 999 888 777 - insert spaces between thousands.

Is there any way how to do it in smarty? I found only smarty spacify modifier, but this insert a string between every character.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You could write a custom filter in PHP. I'm afraid you'll have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use PHP `number_format`

```
{$number|number_format:0:'.':' '}
```